# Why is JavaScript not converting number to floating numbers?

Tags: javascript, html

My javascript loops through a set of tags and take in their innerText which contains floating numbers.

```
var total_amount = 0.00;

function update_totals() {
    total_amount = 0;
    tableRows = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="amount_"]');
    for (var i = 0, len = tableRows.length; i < len; i++) {
        total_amount = total_amount + parseFloat(tableRows[i].innerText).toFixed(2);
        
    }

    tax = parseFloat(total_amount * 5/100).toFixed(2);
    gross_amount = parseFloat(total_amount + tax);

    console.log(total_amount);
    console.log(tax);
    console.log(gross_amount);
}
```

My elements innerText is 3800.00 and 2599.99
But the console.log shows

```
03800.002599.99
Nan
3800.002599
```

Even after giving parseFloat it is considering the values as string.

Required Output

```
6399.99  //3800 + 2599.99
319.99   // 6399 * 5/ 100
6719.98  // sum of two numbers above
```

Comment: `toFixed` returns a string.

Comment: How to round to two digits then?

Comment: `Number(parseFloat(total_amount * 5/100).toFixed(2));` - this will _round up_.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
tax = parseFloat(total_amount * 5/100).toFixed(2);
```

with

```
tax = Number(parseFloat(total_amount * 5/100).toFixed(2));
```